# Rails app with JRuby not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, rubygems, jruby

I have an Rails app which was created on Ubuntu. I wanted to run it on a Mac, but after installing bundles and running `rails s`, I get following errors:

> LoadError: load error: sqlite3/sqlite3_native --
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: failed to load shim library, error:
>   dlopen(/Users/home/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/native/Darwin/libjruby-cext.dylib,
>   10): image not found   require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054
>   (root) at
>   /Users/home/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3.rb:6 
>   require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054    (root) at
>   /Users/home/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:1
>        each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1617   require at /Users/home/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72
>        each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1617   require at /Users/home/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70
>   require at
>   /Users/home/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59
>   require at
>   /Users/home/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132
>   require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054    (root) at
>   /Users/home/workSpace/RubyOnRails/sample_app/config/application.rb:13
>         tap at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1860    (root) at /Users/home/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:1
>   require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054    (root) at script/rails:6

My **Gemfile**:

> source 'https://rubygems.org'
>
> gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
>
> gem 'sqlite3'
>
> group :assets do   gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'   gem
>   'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
>
> gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3' end
>
> gem 'jquery-rails'
>
> gem 'execjs'
>
> group :test, :development do   gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.0" end
>
> gem 'spork'
>
> gem 'webrat'
>
> gem 'heroku'

I am using `jruby 1.7.4 (1.9.3p392) 2013-05-16 2390d3b on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_15-b03 [darwin-x86_64]`
and *Rails 3.2.8*

Comment: Were you using JRuby on Ubuntu as well?

Comment: Nope I didn't use it!

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from the fact that you are trying to use a Ruby gem that relies on a C extension. From the [JRuby wiki](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/C-Extension-Alternatives):

> JRuby versions prior to 1.6 did not support Ruby C extensions, and
>   even in 1.6 the support is still "in development" and considered
>   experimental. As of 1.7, it has been disabled and will likely be
>   removed.

Specifically, the error message states: `dlopen(/Users/home/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/native/Darwin/libjruby-cext.dylib, 10): image not found`. This is attempting to load the JRuby C extension wrapper, which is not found. I'm not sure of the exact cause here, but perhaps it didn't get installed.

As I see it, you have two main options:

1. Install regular MRI instead of JRuby, as you had on Ubuntu. Then you can use gems with C extensions as you wish.
2. From the [same wiki](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/C-Extension-Alternatives): Use [activerecord-jdbc-adapter](https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter) instead along with jdbc-sqlite3. This will allow you to use JRuby, if you need it for your application.

Answer (score 0):

JRuby 1.7.x no longer supports ruby C extensions. See this Jira [ticket](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6091)