# Cannot access Rails console in Windows - LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I'm using JRuby because it's better for SRS Ruby on Rails, on Windows.

My solution was to use `jirb` in cmd.exe or Powershell (not gitbash).

I've tried:

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.4)
Switch to inspect mode.
LoadError: load error: rails/commands -- java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The operation completed successfully.

  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939
    <top> at bin/rails:4
```

and:

```
$ bundle exec rails console
uri:classloader:/jruby/kernel/kernel.rb:17: warning: unsupported exec option: close_others
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.4)
Switch to inspect mode.
LoadError: load error: rails/commands -- java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The operation completed successfully.

  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939
    <top> at bin/rails:4
```

and:

```
$ jruby.exe -S bundle exec rails console
uri:classloader:/jruby/kernel/kernel.rb:17: warning: unsupported exec option: close_others
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.4)
Switch to inspect mode.
LoadError: load error: rails/commands -- java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The operation completed successfully.

  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939
    <top> at bin/rails:4
```

I tried the solution "[Load error when running rails console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23228540/5013141)", but restarting the computer has no effect. bin/spring has no mention of `GEM_HOME`. I reinstalled Rails and Spring.

Is this because of JRuby?

I'm entertaining the idea that `jruby -S rails console` requires C extensions. I found another way to access the console using JRuby's own jirc. I started with:

```
$ jirb
Switch to inspect mode.
```

then edited ~/.irbrc to include

```
IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :SIMPLE
```

which produced:

```
$ jirb
Switch to inspect mode.
>>
```

which then immediately exits. Doing this:

```
$ jirb puts 'hello'
Switch to inspect mode.
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - puts
  initialize at org/jruby/RubyFile.java:342
        open at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1124
        open at G:/jruby-9.0.1.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/irb/magic-file.rb:7
  initialize at G:/jruby-9.0.1.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/irb/input-method.rb:100
  initialize at G:/jruby-9.0.1.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/irb/context.rb:84
  initialize at G:/jruby-9.0.1.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/irb.rb:426
       start at G:/jruby-9.0.1.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/irb.rb:381
       <top> at G:/jruby-9.0.1.0/bin/jirb:13
```

Since my console is still not working and nothing about jirc is using C extensions, the question is not a duplicate to that one.

Comment: OSX or Linux system ?

Comment: Windows using jruby 9.0.1.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails app with JRuby not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051052/rails-app-with-jruby-not-working)

Comment: Not a duplicate, see edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR use `jirb` in Command Prompt to execute Ruby code.

I never resolved making `rails console` work. This may have to do with my ruby installation being a part of jRuby.

However, `irb` and `jirb` allow me to execute Ruby snippets on the command line with either Command Prompt or Powershell. GitBash doesn't work, says `Switch to inspect mode.` followed by `>>` and then exits.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would try and install jruby to resolve this

See http://jruby.org/getting-started

Then do `bundle` from the root of the project

Comment: Unistalled jruby, deleted jruby directory, installed jruby, installed bundle, ran bundle, installed all gems. Same problem.